# Команда break прерывает цикл и не выводит print после нее, консоль резко закрывается. Почему так?

Tags: python, циклы

```py
i = 1
while 1 == 1:

    print ('hi ' + str(i))
    i += 1

    if i == 10000:
        break

print ('program is over')
```

Comment: может потому, что после вывода последнего сообщения, программе больше нечего делать и она завершается? (у Вас Winows?)

Comment: На самом деле выводит. Просто вы не успеваете увидеть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь `input()`, после `print()`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, если есть возможность, могли бы объяснить почему так работает?

Comment: в моем комментарии это объясняется. а input - это один из способов "заставить программу подождать"

Comment: понял, благодарю, просто в видео у парня работает без input, наверное из-за разных версий:)

Comment: просто он все делает в консоли, а Вы видимо запускаете двойным кликом в проводнике